# AutoCAD 2021 .NET API: Getting all blockreferences in a database?

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, autocad-plugin

just trying to find an efficient way of retrieving blockreferences from a drawing's database so I can explode them. Our shop's CNC mill isn't capable of reading blocks, only geometric entities. Our current export function creates a new drawing for each selected block, recreates it there, and then tries to explode it so the mill can properly read its files - right now we have to explode each new drawing manually, but doing so does achieve the results we want.

Tyler

Answer (score 1):

The following code should explode all first generation block references in model space. Note: It does not explode sub entity block references.

```
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Core;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;

public static class Commands
{
    [CommandMethod("ExplodeAll")]
    public static void ExplodeAll()
    {
        try
        {
            Database database = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database;
            using Transaction transaction = database.TransactionManager.StartTransaction();

            using BlockTable blockTable = transaction.GetObject(database.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;
            ObjectId modelId = blockTable[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace];
            using BlockTableRecord model = transaction.GetObject(modelId, OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTableRecord;

            RXClass rxBlockReference = RXClass.GetClass(typeof(BlockReference));
            foreach (ObjectId id in model)
            {
                if (id.IsNull || id.IsErased || id.IsEffectivelyErased || !id.IsValid)
                    continue;

                if (id.ObjectClass == rxBlockReference)
                {
                    using BlockReference reference = transaction.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockReference;
                    reference.ExplodeToOwnerSpace();
                    reference.Erase();
                }
            }
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```